# Is "kitchen car" an English expression?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, vocabulary

In Japanese katakana expressions, *food trucks* are called **kitchen car**.

Is **kitchen car** used in English?

Comment: I haven't heard it in Australia.

Comment: No, I have never heard one called "kitchen car" in the United States.  It's always "food truck" or maybe something with the specific name of the food, like "taco truck".

Comment: You might hear it in the context of trains. I could imagine someone talking about a "[dining car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_car)" and then by anology talking about a "kitchen car" which is where the food served in the dining car is prepared. But I don't believe separate food-preparation cars are common, so the term "kitchen car" isn't really something people would commonly say and you may have people think you mean "dining car" instead. It definitely doesn't mean "food truck" in my experience in the south-west of England.

Comment: Some British trains used to have [kitchen cars](https://pjbrailwayphotos.piwigo.com/_datas/9/o/6/9o6rl289yj/i/uploads/9/o/6/9o6rl289yj//2017/06/09/20170609232758-48e79eb8-me.jpg), marshalled next to restaurant cars, where, as @RichardWard says, the food was cooked before being served. BR Mark 1 types, as in the picture, had the code RK, but that's getting a bit esoteric for here.

Comment: @RichardWard Thanks for the info. There are too many "kitchen car"s here in Japan especially in the central part of Tokyo but almost everybody buys lunch from kitchen cars not dinner so that dining car sounds a bit funny. Food truck would be finer.

Comment: In English speaking countries, a car is not a van and vice versa.